# How to define accuracy in appBuilder?

Tags: user-interface, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm using Progress-4GL, release 11.6, appBuilder and procedure editor.

I've just created a simple window, containing two buttons, `Button-1` and `Button-2`.
The first one is simply placed on the window, the second too, but afterwards, I have dragged `Button-2` one "entry" larger and one "entry" higher.

The result, in the code, looks as follows:

```
DEFINE BUTTON BUTTON-1 
     LABEL "Button 1" 
     SIZE 15 BY 1.14.

DEFINE BUTTON BUTTON-2 
     LABEL "Button 2" 
     SIZE 16 BY 1.45.
```

As you can see, the size has been increased by 1 (in fact, it's 1.00), the heigth by 0.31.

Are those values hardcoded or are they configurable and in case of the second, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are configurable. Double click on the button (or any of the widgets) to get the property sheet of the widget. Under "Geometry" section on the property sheet, there are fields for width and height. One can enter any value there and the widget gets adjusted accordingly.

[image]